# Disappearing items in menu

Tags: menus, htaccess

I have problem with disappearing items in menu.
I added

```
php_value max_input_vars 7000
php_value suhosin.post.max_vars 7000
php_value suhosin.request.max_vars 7000
```

to my .htaccess but it doesn't help.

Can you help me?

Comment: Please elaborate. How and when do they disappear? How many items do you have? Do you loose one item each time or all of them? Any cut-offs? Randomly? Etc ...

Comment: I don't know when they disappear. I have 8 items, 6 are simple link and 2 are pages. Only these two pages disappear.

Comment: Do you have the *Stealth Publish* plugin installed?

Comment: Yes, it's activated but I don't use it yet. I noticed that items disappearing when I update page.

Comment: This plugin is a [known trouble maker](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/causes-menu-items-to-get-erased?replies=1) regarding missing menu items ;-)